# yet another json / python dict question - how to rearrange subsets of dictionary

Tags: python, json

I know similar questions have been asked thousand of times, but I just cant get it right...
So I have a python script that collects quite a lot of meta data in this form:

```
[
    {
        "category": "alpha",
        "metaset": [
            {
                "file": "/mnt/c/Users/1234566.txt",
                "title": "Lorep",
                "author": "Peter",
                "language": "French",
                "status": "Completed"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "alpha",
        "metaset": [
            {
                "file": "/mnt/c/Users/897367.txt",
                "title": "something else",
                "author": "00",
                "language": "English",
                "status": "Completed"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "bravo",
        "metaset": [
            {
                "file": "/mnt/c/Users/087849.txt",
                "title": "triple",
                "author": "Joe",
                "language": "English",
                "status": "Completed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

All this is a variable in my python script.

Now I want to write a json file. But I want to make the structure to be sorted to the categories. Something like this:

```
{
    "alpha": [{
            "file": "/mnt/c/Users/1234566.txt",
            "title": "Lorep",
            "author": "Peter",
            "language": "French",
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "file": "/mnt/c/Users/897367.txt",
            "title": "something else",
            "author": "00",
            "language": "English",
            "status": "Completed"
        }
    ],
    "bravo": [{
        "file": "/mnt/c/Users/087849.txt",
        "title": "triple",
        "author": "Joe",
        "language": "English",
        "status": "Completed"
    }]
}
```

I could also still change how the source structure looks like, but the base question is, how do I filter and grep subsets of this dictionary and arrange it in a new one?

Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: If there are so many similar questions, why did none of them help you? What did you try? What exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, just do:

```
group = defaultdict(list)  # requires from collections import defaultdict
for d in data:
    group[d['category']].extend(d['metaset'])

res = {k: group[k] for k in sorted(group)}
pprint.pprint(res) # requires import pprint
```

**Output**

```
{'alpha': [{'author': 'Peter',
            'file': '/mnt/c/Users/1234566.txt',
            'language': 'French',
            'status': 'Completed',
            'title': 'Lorep'},
           {'author': '00',
            'file': '/mnt/c/Users/897367.txt',
            'language': 'English',
            'status': 'Completed',
            'title': 'something else'}],
 'bravo': [{'author': 'Joe',
            'file': '/mnt/c/Users/087849.txt',
            'language': 'English',
            'status': 'Completed',
            'title': 'triple'}]}
```